# how to make the macOS terminal to use proxy

Tags: macos, iterm

When I am using iterm in macOS 12.4, need the terminal also could use proxy. I have already set the system proxy to use sockets.

[image]

this works fine in Google Chrome, and in macOS termimal, I changed the proxy setting in `.zshrc` like this:

```
alias proxy='export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890'
```

When I want to use proxy in terminal, just type the proxy command, seems did not work as expect, I still could not access google from terminal. what should I do to make the proxy work in terminal?

Comment: The terminal does not use any proxies it just runs and displays shells. What command are you trying to use with a proxy?

Comment: `fvm install 2.5.0`. @mmmmmm

Comment: How does that access google?

Comment: I am using the command `curl -L www.google.com` in terminal.@mmmmmm

Comment: The curl manpage says the environment variable is ALL_PROXY ie all in capitals so try that